# Error message while working with mocking in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

Sorry for the bad title.

Im trying to do some Unit Test. I have the following controller:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository repository;
    public int PageSize = 4;
    //Declar the dependency on IProductRepository
    public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
    {
        this.repository = productRepository;
    }
    // GET: Product

    public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
    {
    return View(repository.Products.OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).Skip((page-1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize));
    }
}
```

Im going to unit test the page pagination.

Here Is my Unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Can_Paginate()
{
    //Arrange
    Mock<IProductRepository> mock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new Product[]
    {
        new Product {ProductID = 1, Name = "P1" },
        new Product {ProductID = 2, Name = "P2" },
        new Product {ProductID = 3, Name = "P3" },
        new Product {ProductID = 4, Name = "P4" },
        new Product {ProductID = 5, Name = "P5" }
    });

    ProductController controller = new ProductController(mock.Object);
            controller.PageSize = 3;

    //Act
    IEnumerable<Product> result = (IEnumerable<Product>)controller.List(2).Model;

    //Assert
    Product[] prodArray = result.ToArray();
    Assert.IsTrue(prodArray.Length == 2);
    Assert.AreEqual(prodArray[0].Name, "P4");
    Assert.AreEqual(prodArray[1].Name, "P5");
}
```

I get the following error message In my test file:

[image]

What does this mean?

Comment: your project dll use newer dll than the dll you referenced in your test project. just remove the dll from your test project and than add the correct one.

Comment: @OldFox: How do I remove the dll?

Comment: I posted it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project dll use newer dll than the dll you referenced in your test project. just remove the dll from your test project and than add the correct one:

Select the test project in Solution explorer -> References -> right click on System.Web.Mvc -> remove ([How to: Add or Remove References](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx))

Than add the correct version of System.Web.Mvc which is 5.2.3.0

**Edit**

The ASP.NET MVC has a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/). This is correct way to add the assembly

Comment: Should I choose the Framework och Extension in the Assemblies tab?

Comment: @Bryan I don't know the exact location, but if you click on the assembly then you'll see the version on the right panel.

Comment: Yes, but how do I add a new version of the dll?

Comment: @Bryan the Dll which you are looking for has a nuget package. Right click on References -> Manage nuget packages -> in the search box type mvc and then add the package.(I edited my answer)